# How do I ignore CSS Module imports in a Next.js component that cause parse errors in unit tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, css-modules

I'm using CSS Modules in my Next.js project (I'm new to Next.js) and testing with [Riteway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/riteway). When I run unit tests for React components, any component that imports a CSS Module fails with a SyntaxError because it can't parse the CSS file being imported. I already had to create a `.babelrc` file to handle parsing JSX in the tests so that it copies the Next.js config (`{ "presets": ["next/babel"], "plugins": [] }`) and activating it with `-r @babel/register` as part of my test command, but it doesn't seem to be handling the CSS Modules.

How can I configure my code to at least not choke on the CSS Module import and make it so `styles` in `import styles from './styles.module.css';` is an empty object so that all the `styles.myClass` references don't break? It's unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be any docs regarding sharing the Babel config with other run contexts like unit tests, only [how to customize your Babel config](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config) if you need to.

**Component file**

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './styles.module.css'`;

export default () => (
  <div className={styles.root}>
    Content
  </div>
);
```

**Component CSS Module**

```css
.root {
  background: green;
}
```

**Component test file**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { describe } from 'riteway';
import render from 'riteway/render-component';

import MyComponent from './component.jsx';

describe('<MyComponent>', async assert => {
  const $ = render(<MyComponent />);

  assert({
    given: 'rendering the component',
    should: 'render',
    actual: $('body > div').length,
    expected: 1,
  });
});
```

**Test command**

```
$ NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register -r regenerator-runtime src/path/to/component.test.jsx
```

**Test command result**

```sh
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .root {
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:258:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:306:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/path/to/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging further, there's an [`ignore-styles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-styles) package that you can use as `-r @babel/register -r ignore-styles` and that seems to make it work. Not sure whether it's the best option, but it unblocks me. I'm still open to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`babel-plugin-module-name-mapper`](https://github.com/mgcrea/babel-plugin-module-name-mapper) into your `plugins` in your `.babelrc`.

```
[
  "module-name-mapper",
  {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.css$": "<rootDir>/src/helpers/mock/style-mock.js"
     }
  }
]
```

Here `style-mock.js` simply exports an empty object.

```js
module.exports = {};
```

What this will do is, it will replace all css with an empty object since you shouldn't test your styles with unit tests anyways. (You should use [visual regression tests](https://youtu.be/f-znW60j1Es?t=3142) for that.)